# Serialize Object/Object[] entries to gson JsonObject

Tags: java, arrays, json, serialization, gson

I am reading a resource from a backend that is giving me an Map of entries. I am iterating these and retriving the values. The type of that value is object or object[], the actual types are common primitives or a Calender class.

My target is to create a json response, it should look like this:

```json
{
    "testUri": "https://www.google.de",
    "testDate": 1636986289929,
    "testLong": "123123",
    "testName": "name",
    "testPath": "path",
    "indexName": "AAA_de_de_offers",
    "testArrayDate": [1636986289929],
    "testArrayLong": [111, 222, 333],
    "testArrayUri": ["http://www.google.de", "http://www.test.de"],
    "testArrayDouble": [1.2, 2.1, 3.1],
    "testBoolean": "true",
    "testArrayBoolean": [true, true, false],
    "regex": "ASDASD",
    "suggestHeadline": "Beliebte Suchbegriffe",
    "testDecimal": "12",
    "testArrayDecimal": [1, 2, 3],
    "testDouble": "12.87",
    "testString": "testString"
}
```

But I am really unhappy with the result, since I am repeating a lot of checks and methods that are doing the same , the only thing that differs is are the types.

The first step I am doing is to check which class I am facing

```
Object value = e.getValue();

final boolean valIsDate = value instanceof Calendar;
final boolean valIsDateArray = Calendar[].class.equals(value.getClass());
final boolean valIsDouble = Double.class.equals(value.getClass());
final boolean valIsDoubleArray = Double[].class.equals(value.getClass());
final boolean valIsLong = Long.class.equals(value.getClass());
final boolean valIsLongArray = Long[].class.equals(value.getClass());
final boolean valIsBoolean = Boolean.class.equals(value.getClass());
final boolean valIsBooleanArray = Boolean[].class.equals(value.getClass());
final boolean valIsBigDecimal = BigDecimal.class.equals(value.getClass());
final boolean valIsBigDecimalArray = BigDecimal[].class.equals(value.getClass());
final boolean valIsString = value instanceof String;
final boolean valIsStringArray = String[].class.equals(value.getClass());
```

After that I am creating the json entries with the help of a big if clause

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
if (valIsStringArray) {
    json.add(key, getJsonArray((String[]) value));
} else if (valIsDate) {
    json.addProperty(key, ((Calendar) value).getTimeInMillis());
} else if (valIsDateArray) {
    json.add(key, getJsonArray((Calendar[]) value));
} else if (valIsDouble) {
    json.addProperty(key, (Double) value);
} else if (valIsDoubleArray) {
    json.add(key, getJsonArray((Double[]) value));
} else if (valIsLong) {
    json.addProperty(key, (Long) value);
} else if (valIsLongArray) {
    json.add(key, getJsonArray((Long[]) value));
} else if (valIsBoolean) {
    json.addProperty(key, (Boolean) value);
} else if (valIsBooleanArray) {
    json.add(key, getJsonArray((Boolean[]) value));
} else if (valIsBigDecimal) {
    json.addProperty(key, gson.toJson(value, BigDecimal.class));
} else if (valIsBigDecimalArray) {
    json.add(key, getJsonArray((BigDecimal[]) value));
} else {
    // String is the default fallback
    json.addProperty(key, valueAsString);
}
```

getJsonArray is receiving the array types and creating JsonArray entries
for example

```
protected JsonArray getJsonArray(final Calendar[] arrayAsObject) {
        final JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
        for (final Calendar e : arrayAsObject) {
            jsonArray.add(e.getTimeInMillis());
        }
        return jsonArray;
    }
```

Im sure theres a better way to achieve this :)

Comment: Can you explain _what_ exactly are you trying to _archieve_? The only goal I can see in your question is the chain of `instanceof` checks and dispatching, but you're missing to tell what you want to achieve (+ lacking the code that to complete your question), and I seem to believe the goal is achievable in a more simple way.

Comment: I've added some further informations for my target. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: I don't get it, why not simply create a mapping class with all of the fields like `class DataBag { String testUri; long testLong; long[] testArrayLong[] ; ... }` and let Gson do the job itself?

Comment: I am reading different ressources that create different json responses. That one was just an example. So unfortunatly I cannot create a mapping class. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `toJsonTree` method that recognizes automatically the object class.

```java
json.add(key, new Gson().toJsonTree(value));
```

Comment: It looks valid, but the result of this is not the correct JsonPrimitive type. For the cases boolean, BigDecimal, double and long it simpy creates a JsonPrimitive String value. So instead of getting "testBoolean": true I get "testBoolean": "true"  

Regarding the Array types, it does simply the same. "testArrayBoolean": [true, true, false] would be "testArrayBoolean": "["true", "true", "false"]",

Comment: I edited the answer using `toJsonTree`. This method works also for the cases you wrote in the comment.